# Range SeekBar With Two Thumbs Not Working

Tags: android, layout, seekbar

I am using RangeSeekBar in my app by referring this [RangeSeekBar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/). I have two issues with this `seekbar`. And  i am using this seekbar in a fragment.

1) I am able to see the `seekbar` in my emulator with android `api 19` configuration. But on Touch events are not working for the thumbs.

2) In device i am not able to see the `seekbar` at all. My device is having `Android 4.0.4 OS`.

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/colors_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/metricsSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qtyOptionsSpinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/qtyOptionsSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `seekbar` appears below the `GridView`.

Here is my code:

```
RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(5,50,this.getActivity());

mParentLayout.addView(seekBar, layoutParams);

seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
        // handle changed range values
        Log.i("TAG", "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue+ ", MAX=" + maxValue);
    }
});
```

Pls help me asap.

Answer (score -2):

Its all because of my layout structure. I changed my layout structure in such a way that i have an empty Relative layout as a child to the parent layout.Then I dynamically add my SeekBar to that child relative layout.

On changing my layout I got two of my issues posted above solved.